# Permission Denied on shared object (.so) file postgresql

Tags: postgresql, functions

I'm trying to import a C-Language function to my postgresql database.

I have my shared object inside my home directory but I can't use it on my database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_one(integer) RETURNS integer AS '/home/pedro/.../.../example.so', 'add_one' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

And this is my error message:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "/home/pedro/.../.../example.so": Permission denied
```

I think is probably my OS blocking access to this file but I don't want to give permission to all users.

tl;dr: I'm looking for a elegant solution to import my C-Language Function, as a Shared Object file, inside my postgresql database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just copy your .so to a directory where postgres can read it. If you need a hint on where files are typically located by function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions on the path and file should be `postgres:postgres`.

```
ls -l /home/pedro/.../.../example.so
chown -R postgres: /home/pedro/.../.../
```

You will probably need `sudo` for changing the file ownership.

Comment: So I've tried: `sudo chown postgres: /home/pedro/.../.../example.so` and `sudo chmod u+rX /home/pedro/.../.../example.so` and it didn't work.

Running:  `ls -l /home/pedro/.../.../example.so`
I get: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres 12952 Aug 17 17:42 /home/pedro/.../.../example.so`

Tried with my user (pedro) and (postgres) user.

Comment: The `chown` command above has -R option, which changes the directory and recursively the ownership. The dir must be accessible to the user `postgres` too. @PedroCaldeira